# How do I use activityScenarioRule<Activity>?

Tags: android, androidx

I'm following the dev guide here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing

and have a test class like:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTestSuite {
   @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MyActivity>()

   @Test fun testEvent() {
    val scenario = activityScenarioRule.scenario
   }
}
```

the method `activityScenarioRule<T>()` is not defined. What dependency do I need? Also, what is the best way to determine which dependencies to add when reading these docs?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `activityScenarioRule<T>()` method is part of the `androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.0` dependency.

Usually, this would be listed under the [List of AndroidX Test dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#android-test-dependencies), but it appears it isn't up to date with the `junit-ktx` or `core-ktx` modules as of yet, despite it being explicitly mentioned as part of the [Version 1.1.0-beta01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test#1.1.0-b1)

Comment: Do I need to add a static import to reference it?

Comment: You'll need to add an import, yes. But it isn't a static import.

Comment: Hmm, still not seeing it. It does look like `launchActivity` is now available though.

Comment: Ah, yeah, looks like `activityScenarioRule` is part of the `androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx` module, not the `core-ktx` module (which has the `launchActivity` equivalent).

Comment: The `activityScenarioRule`  causes my build to fail for: `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.7 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`

Comment: @ZeroDivide - sounds like you should [compile with Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) and [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964) to get the documentation updated to point that out.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not using the ktx dependency, e.g. `androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2` you can do it like this:

```
@get:Rule
var activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MyActivity::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

My example of usage `ActivityScenarioRule<>` for **Java**:

```
public class AdMobContainerImplTest {
    private static final String TAG = AdMobContainerImplTest.class.getSimpleName();
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<ENDetailsActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(
            ENDetailsActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testAdVisibility() {
        mActivityRule.getScenario().onActivity(activity -> {
            AdView ad = activity.findViewById(R.id.ad_banner);
            ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    Log.i(TAG, "ad loaded");
                    Assert.assertNotNull(ad);
                    onView(withId(R.id.ad_banner)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Changing dependency from `testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'`
to  `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'` worked for me.

Comment: This only works for if you are running instrumentation tests is the androidTest folder. You need testImplementation for running unit tests in the test folder.